# Quartz.NET в трехуровневой архитектуре. С#

Tags: c#, таймер, quartz

Есть класс, который унаследован от интерфейса IJob. Экемпляр этого класса у меня создается через реализацию интерфейс. В конструкторе этого класса я вызываю метод для настройки кварца `ExecuteTimeBuilder.Start();`

Код

```html
public class CalculateManager : ICalculateManager, IJob
    {
        private readonly IStrongDataRepository _strongDataRepository;
   

        public CalculateManager(IStrongDataRepository strongDataRepository)
        {

            _strongDataRepository = strongDataRepository;

            ExecuteTimeBuilder.Start();
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HelloJob is executing.");
        }

    }
```

Метод .Start()

```html
public static async void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CalculateManager>()
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()  
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")     
                .StartNow()                           
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x           
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)    
                    .RepeatForever())         
                .Build();        
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);   
        }
```

У меня просто не срабатывает метод Execute. это консольное приложение .Core 3.0
Интерфейсы регестрируются в кастомном классе StartUp

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);

            services.AddSingleton<IStrongDataRepository, StrongDataRepository>();

            services.AddSingleton<ICalculateManager, CalculateManager>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

Почему кварц просто игнорирует конфиг и не запускает метод Execute